# Every element of a Hilbert space is not orthogonal to at most countably many elements of an uncountable orthonormal system

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $\{ e_r \}_{r>0}$ an uncountable orthonormal system in a Hilbert space $H$, prove that for every $v \in H$ $\langle v, e_r \rangle \neq 0$ for at most countably many $r>0$.

If we assume $\{ e_r \}_{r>0}$ is complete then because we are in a Hilbert space it means that $\{ e_r \}_{r>0}$ is a basis and hence for every $v \in H$ we have $v = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ie_i$ hence $\langle e_r,v \rangle \neq 0$ only for $r \in \mathbb{N}$ indeed.

How to go about the other case? tried in many ways but cannot find a proof

Comment: In the other case, we can always add vectors until it is complete, and then apply the argument you presented.

Comment: Thanks, not sure though, how do we know that only countably many additions to the system can form a basis?

Comment: Even if infinitely many additions are required, in the final result only finitely many will be non-zero, due to your argument.  See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $\{e_r\}$ is orthonormal means that we can complete it to a basis $\{e_r\}\cup\{f_s\}$.  Then since we are in a Hilbert space, your reasoning implies that $\langle e_r,v \rangle \neq 0$ or $\langle f_s,v \rangle \neq 0$ only for a countable number of indices $r,s$.  But, since $\{e_r\}\subseteq\{e_r\}\cup\{f_s\}$, then in particular the number of indices $r$ for which $\langle e_r,v \rangle \neq 0$ is also countable.